# Can't disable window (radio buttons) in my tab WIN32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to disable the radio buttons when I select the checkbox. It works when I pass `hwnd` in `addFunc2()`, however, I need it to be in the second tab but somehow I can't find any way to make it work.

I apologize if its confusing, I'm very new at this, and my first time posting here. Please let me know if I need to clarify it more. Please refer to the images and some of my code below:

Result of code:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

```
HWND hRadio1, hRadio2, hTab, g_tabPanes[2];

HWND CreateTabPane(HWND tabctrl, int id, HINSTANCE instance)
{
    RECT rcTab;
    GetClientRect(tabctrl, &rcTab);
    TabCtrl_AdjustRect(tabctrl, FALSE, &rcTab);
    int wd = rcTab.right - rcTab.left;
    int hgt = rcTab.bottom - rcTab.top;
    return CreateWindow(
        L"static", L"",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        rcTab.left, rcTab.top, wd, hgt,
        tabctrl,
        (HMENU)id,
        instance,
        NULL
    );
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        addControl(hwnd);

        HINSTANCE hInst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        RECT rc; int dx, dy;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        dx = rc.right - rc.left;
        dy = rc.bottom - rc.top;

        TCITEM tie = {
            TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_IMAGE,
            0, 0,
            NULL,
            0, -1, 0
        };

        hTab = CreateWindowEx(NULL, WC_TABCONTROL, _T(""),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
            0, 0, dx, dy, hwnd,
            (HMENU)1001, hInst, NULL
        );

        tie.pszText = (LPWSTR)_T("Tab 1");
        TabCtrl_InsertItem(hTab, 0, &tie);
        tie.pszText = (LPWSTR)_T("Tab 2");
        TabCtrl_InsertItem(hTab, 1, &tie);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            g_tabPanes[i] = CreateTabPane(hTab, TAB_ID + i, hInst);

        addFunc1(g_tabPanes[0]);
        addFunc2(g_tabPanes[1]);

        break;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case ID_CHECKBOX:
        {
            switch (HIWORD(wParam))
            {
            case BN_CLICKED:
                if (SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, ID_CHECKBOX, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0))
                {
                    EnableWindow(hRadio1, true);
                    EnableWindow(hRadio2, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    EnableWindow(hRadio1, false);
                    EnableWindow(hRadio2, false);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        break;

    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        LPNMHDR ns = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
        if ((ns->idFrom == 1001) && (ns->code == TCN_SELCHANGE))
        {
            int pane = TabCtrl_GetCurSel(hTab);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                if (pane == i)
                    ShowWindow(g_tabPanes[i], SW_SHOW);
                else
                    ShowWindow(g_tabPanes[i], SW_HIDE);
        }
    }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

void addFunc2(HWND hwnd)
{
    HWND hCheckbox;
    CreateWindow(TEXT("static"), TEXT("Duplex: "), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        75, 10, 90, 25, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    hCheckbox = CreateWindow(L"button", L"Print on both sides", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | 
    BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,
        75, 30, 150, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_CHECKBOX, g_hinst, NULL);

    hRadio1 = CreateWindow(L"button", L"Flip on long edge", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | 
    BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP,
        75, 55, 150, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_RADIO1, g_hinst, NULL);

    hRadio2 = CreateWindow(L"button", L"Flip on short edge", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | 
    BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP,
        75, 80, 150, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_RADIO2, g_hinst, NULL);

    SendMessage(hCheckbox, BM_SETCHECK, BST_CHECKED, 0);
    SendMessage(hRadio1, BM_SETCHECK, BST_CHECKED, 0);
```

Comment: Button controls send notifications to their parent window. If you make them the child of a static control, the notifications will go to that static control which doesn't know what to do with them. The standard way to do this is to use a child dialog, with its own dialog procedure.

Comment: Thank youu, I managed to make it work, didn't know static control was the cause for this. I appreciate it!